# 3D bar Graphs, Axes and resolution

Tags: plotting, charts

```
data = {{10,5,2,1,Missing[],Missing[],Missing[],Missing[],Missing[]},{10,8,6,1,Missing[],Missing[],Missing[],Missing[]},{10,10,6,4,2,Missing[],Missing[],Missing[],Missing[]},{10,10,10,10,10,7,10,3,4},{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}};

BarChart3D[data,
BarSpacing-> {1,0.5}, 
ChartLayout-> "Grid",
ChartLabels ->{{"0.05","0.1","1.0","2.0","3.0"},{" 0.18","0.20","0.20","0.20","0.25","0.27","0.28","0.28","0.32"}},
TicksStyle ->{False,False,True},
ViewPoint-> {3.33,-8.26,3.36},
ImageSize->Large]
```

If you plot this code, on the y-axis chart labels will be on top of one another.  How would I go about resolving this?

Is there any way to increase the resolution of the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1 - one array in `data` has fewer elements than the others.
Problem #2 - Whether it's a bug or not, BarChart3D isn't working well with `Missing[]`.

If I understand the problem correctly, you can work around the overlapping tick labels by deleting instances of Missing.  Assuming that data cannot change (or you want the Missing[] elements in for other purposes):

```
BarChart3D[DeleteCases[data, _Missing, 2], BarSpacing -> {1, 0.5}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ChartLabels -> {{"0.05", "0.1", "1.0", "2.0", "3.0"}, {" 0.18", 
    "0.20", "0.20", "0.20", "0.25", "0.27", "0.28", "0.28", "0.32"}}, 
 TicksStyle -> {False, False, False}, 
 ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 3.36}, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]